# Creating an Ask Different Style Guide

Tags: discussion, formatting

## Ask Different Style Guide

I've been going through the *Suggested Edits* review queue and of late, there's been some wild "swings" in terms of the formatting (i.e. code, menu, keyboard, etc.), technical terminology, capitalization, etc.  leading to very inconstant usage of formatting conventions.

I was thinking that we could come up with an "Ask Different Style Guide" of which we could refer to for consistency in posts and in edits.  It could be based off of [Apple's own official style guide](https://help.apple.com/applestyleguide/#/?sub=apde23dc814b) but be very much *simplified* as we don't need anything *that* formal or complex.    The ultimate goal would to follow Apple's lead and strive toward some consistency in phraseology.  Think of it as Ask Different's version of "[Conventions Used in this Manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19796-01/819-2661/6n4uetjqo/index.html)"

For example, we have `code formatting` for, well identifying code or text commands.  It's been used for everything from identifying keystrokes instead of using <kbd>Key</kbd> formatting, highlighting menu selections, notating operating system versions, identifying web site addresses to separating sections in an answer rather than using headers.  Obviously, this can be confusing, but if I you have even the slightest bit of OCD, it can lead to a stroke.

My idea is to "level up" Ask Different and make us stand out.  We have some fantastic minds on here and it would simply be awesome if Internet searches brought people to the *official unofficial question/answer site for everything Apple.*

#### Getting started

I'm thinking that we could each contribute via an "answer" and format it with two sections:

- Issue
- Proposed styling

As for compiling and creating the final guide, I'm more than happy to contribute (but I wouldn't be too bashful to turn down any assistance. I'd really like this to be a community effort.  I'm open to any format or methodology.  Comments, questions...let me know!

Comment: Fantastic idea: howto format markdown *and* how to use it properly (that's not only useful *here*). Although I'd suggest strongly that individual answers may be posted here, but then added to a curated community wiki at the top of this thread? I'd start with adding people abusing 'code-ticks' for inline quotes, just to alter text background.

Comment: Not limited to markdown @LаngLаngС but how to properly reference products (i.e. Mac and not MAC).  A proper style guide like you’d find in academic settings. And I am very much in agreement re: misuse of code ticks!

Comment: You may also explain how this should relate to the document https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/editing and the resulting impetus on 'when & what to edit' (ie ~ make it substantial; try to fix everything you see…)